# Hybrid USB Install Method - netboot and iso

Tags: installation, 12.10, usb-drive

I was following the steps here ("Preparing Files for USB Memory Stick Booting")

- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/boot-usb-files.html

to create a installation usb drive for 12.1. The very first paragraph of the article states

- "The second is to also copy a CD image onto the USB stick and use that as a source for packages, possibly **in combination with a mirror**."

However, the only instructions mentioned regarding an iso image is to simply copy one somewhere on the drive (after its been made bootable and syslinux, vmlinuz and initrd.gz installed/copied):

- "you should now copy an Ubuntu ISO image onto the stick."

I thought it strange there where no configuration steps for "pointing" the kernel to the iso (like a line in syslinux.cfg or a boot: option or something), but went ahead with the install anyway.

I don't think the iso was used at all, it appeared that all the OS files where downloaded during the install process.

**Therefore, I was wondering if anyone knew how to use this local iso image in this particular installation technique** (I know the image can be installed with dd, but thats a  different technique), b/c I need to reinstall (I installed unity, but it's wayy to much for my little Atom based netbook) ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/128995/grub2-loopback-booting-ubuntu-server-iso

Answer (score 0):

Unity probably will be too much for your atom based netbook... Try xubuntu/Lubuntu. If you need USB creatro from windows, use one of the tutorials here: (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/). if you need the same from linux, i prefer Multisystem (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

Comment: Yes, **"I need to reinstall (I installed unity, but it's wayy to much for my little Atom based netbook)"**... But, when I do reinstall, **"I was wondering if anyone knew how to use this local iso image in this particular installation technique"**... I'm aware of the other methods, but am trying to install with this particular method: **https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/boot-usb-files.html**

Comment: then sorry, I do not like this method as it lacks a multiboot option.

Comment: Its ok, I wasn't yelling (with the bold), just clarifying... I appreciate the help, maybe those links will have my answer (I've been doing a lot of reading myself, but posted this the meantime)...